# How to install golang package with custom tags in nix-shell?

Tags: go, nix

I want to use [go-migrate](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate) in my development environment, so I fill my `shell.nix` with

```hs
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:

pkgs.mkShell {
  buildInputs = [
    pkgs.go-migrate
  ];
}
```

But it will install `go-migrate` without any database drivers, so I can't use it. As I see in [official installation instructions](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/tree/master/cmd/migrate#unversioned) I should provide tags with needed database, but how to do it with nix?

Comment: This has not been documented yet and the go-migrate package needs a new maintainer.

Comment: Maybe you need to repackage it yourself, setting [`buildFlagsArray`](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#ssec-go-common-attributes), but regardless, this warrants an issue in the Nixpkgs repo.